# Getting data from an Activity in a Fragment

Tags: android, android-activity, fragment

I've set up a fragment inside my activity, but I'm wondering how I can pass data from the activity into the fragment?

For example, this is my code:

```
    public class MyFragment extends Fragment 
{   
    private MyData _myData;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {   
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment 
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_fragment, container, false);

        MyActivity activity = (MyActivity) getActivity(); // Unreachable code error here
        _myData = activity.getMyData();
    }
}
```

I need to be able to access the contents of the `MyData` object in the fragment. But when I try this code above, I get an "Unreachable Code" error, even though `getMyData()` is a public method in the `MyActivity` class.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This line is the problem

```
return inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_fragment_make_assembly_machine_location, container, false);
```

The return statement makes the function... return!, so following code never gets executed!

Comment: How could I have missed that! Thanks, that of course fixed it :)

Answer (score 2):

You have a return statement before

```
MyActivity activity = (MyActivity) getActivity();
```

Move the return statement to the last

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {   
        MyActivity activity = (MyActivity) getActivity(); 
        _myData = activity.getMyData();
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_fragment, container, false);
    }
```

Also you may want to check

[Send data from activity to fragment in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12739909/send-data-from-activity-to-fragment-in-android)